# Relative change in div position

Tags: jquery, css

Here is my structure to divide my page in 3 section:

division is 15 - 65 -20

I have one div in right section with ID `alchemy`. I want to set the height of this div

`<div style="height:150px;">`.

But if I put height here, the middle section also appear at height `150px` why?

```
<tr>
    <div class="left">
  <td style="width:15%">
    <div style="position:absolute">
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/
<?php echo $user_id; ?>
/picture?type=large" style="position:fixed; top:60px; left:1px;">
      </div>
  </td>
</div>
<div class="middle">
  <td style="width:65%">
    <div class="input-button-collection">
      <div id="input-collection" class="input-group input-group-lg">

        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link">
          </i>
        </span>

        <input id="url-input-box" type="url" class="form-control" name="url" placeholder="http://www.example.com">
      </div>
      <div id="error-msg" class="help-block">

        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign">
        </i>
        URL is invalid
      </div>
      <div class="rating-collection">
        <input type="number" name="rating" id="rating-input" class="rating" />
        <div>

          <span id="error-msg-rating" class="help-block">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign">
            </i>
            Please choose a rating
          </span>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-input-button">
        <button id="submit-url-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
          Get Sentiment
        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="old-records" align="center">
      </div>
    </td>
  </div>
<div class="right">
  <td style="width:20%">
    <!-- 
<?php include 'logout.php'; ?>
-->
          <div id="alchemy" style="overflow:hidden; clear:both">
          </div>
      </td>
</div>
</tr>
```

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: how did you indent the code?

Comment: @JohnConde: done by ohgodwhy!

Comment: What'cha mean? I just edited your post and reindented it.

Comment: @cyclic you can use jsfiddle.net for that (TidyUp)

Comment: TD inside a DIV ... amazing

Answer (score 0):

This code is a mess :

You got some `<td>` into `<div>` tags : this should not be. `td` parent must be a `tr` (table-row).

You should read [documentation about HTML tables](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) and correct your code : this is not fixable since this is not valid.

Comment: @OlivierH: `<tr>` is already there I missed to mention it! even I upvote for your effort!

Comment: Read the documentation again. **ABSOLUTELY NOTHING MUST BE BETWEEN TR AND TD TAGS**.